# Задача на Паскаль, решение дискриминанта

Tags: pascal

Мне надо решить задачу на Pascal, но у меня выходит ошибка

```pascal
    Program kwur; {Имя программы}
    Uses Crt; {Использование библиотечного модуля CRT}
    Var a, b, c, d, w, z, x1, x2:Real; {Объявление переменных}
        otvet: Char;
    
    Begin {Начало основного блока программы}
        Clrscr; {Очистка экрана}
        Writeln('Вы работаете с программой вычисления корней');
        Writeln('квадратного уравнения общего вида ахх+bx+c=0');

        Repeat; {Начало цикла с постусловием}
            Write ('Введите значение b=');
            Readln (b);
            Write ('Введите значение с=');
            Readln (c);
            
            D:=b*b-4*a*c; {Вычисление дискриминанта}
            Z:=-b/(2*a);
            Writeln ('При a=',a:5:2, 'b=',b:5:2, 'c=',c:5:2);
            If D<0 Then
            Begin
                Writeln ('X1=',Z:6:3, '+j*',w:5:3);
                Writeln ('X2=',Z:6:3, '-j*',w:5:3);
            End
            Else
            Begin
                X1:=z+w;
                X2:=z-w;
                Writeln ('x1=',x1:5:2, 'x2=',x2:5:2);
            End
        End;
            Writeln ('Желаете продолжить работу? (y/n)');
            Readln (otvet);
        Until otvet < > 'y'; {Повторять, пока переменная otvet примет значение, отличное от у}
        Writeln ('Спасибо! До свидания!');
    End.
```

Выходит такая ошибка: main.pas(29,5) Fatal: Syntax error, "UNTIL" expected but "END" found
Паскаль недавно начал изучать, пытался Until переставить выше End но ошибка никак не уходит.
Пожалуйста подскажите что я делаю не так

Comment: убери ``;`` после repeat. И посмотри в других местах, может где-то лишние, где-то не хватает. После ``end``, например, то есть, то нет. Вряд ли это правильно.

Comment: Тут еще `End;` лишний. В общем учите основый конструкций языка ...

Answer (score 0):

Если я не ошибаюсь, после `Repeat` точка с запятой не нужна.
И у вас лишний `End`

```
Repeat; {Начало цикла с постусловием}
....
    End; {вот тут лишний!!!}
        Writeln ('Желаете продолжить работу? (y/n)');
        Readln (otvet);
Until otvet < > 'y';
```